# Is there Early Stop in Stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: gradient

Let's say I have 100 data points. If stochastic gradient didn't converge at first round of 100 data points, then I need to continue another round. Then if it converged at 50th data point, so total number data I've fed is 100+50=150. My question is, do we just stop or do we need to feed the rest 50 to the model?
PS: Andrew Ng's note doesn't specify when to stop.[image]

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/q/14464612/2954547

Comment: @ssdecontrol Yes!  So I guess the "if...break..." should be right after the 3rd line, inside the for-loop, right?